# concatenation of JavaScript code for jQuery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

In the following code some concatenation is needed to put all the lines into PlayersDetail variable so that a div named PlayersList can be appended.

```
var onlineStatus="online";
PlayersDetail='Here is some text before if statement.<br>'
if (onlineStatus==="online"){
   'I am online.<br>'
}
'here is some text after if statement.'
$("#PlayersList").append(PlayersDetail);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use concatenation operator

```
var onlineStatus = "online";

PlayersDetail = 'Here is some text before if statement.<br>'
if (onlineStatus === "online") {
    //use concatenation operators
    PlayersDetail += 'I am online.<br>'
    //same as 
   // PlayersDetail = PlayersDetail + 'I am online.<br>'
}
//use concatenation operators
PlayersDetail += 'here is some text after if statement.'

$("#PlayersList").append(PlayersDetail);
```